# help canot connect?

Tags: configuration

i have been able to connect to this site previously no problems but fot the last weekor two i have been getting

Unable to connect

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at pwoah7foa6au2pul.onion.

```
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Tor Browser is permitted to access the Web.
```

i able to surf tor no problem but serten sights all i get is this!!
not to sure is it a proxy issue? if so some help pleas
thanks
      coeddan

Answer (score 0):

Since you're able to visit other websites as usual, this seems to be a problem with that particular website, as it's mentioned on the error:

`The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy.`

Doesn't seem to have anything to do with proxies.